# Creating wallet on Blockchain with Ajax gives CORS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bitcoin, blockchain

I am trying to create wallet on Blockchain using Ajax but I am getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error. My Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://blockchain.info/api/v2/create_wallet',
                    data: "cors=true&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&api_code="+code,
                     dataType:'json',
crossDomain: true,
                     beforeSend:function(){


                      },
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
            });
```

When I post this I get error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blockchain.info/api/v2/create_wallet. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

[On Blockchain](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api) they say that **Some API calls are available with CORS headers if you add a cors=true parameter to the request**

I have tried everything, I have tried to send this parameter as a GET as well as POST parameter, I have tried **jsonp**. I have also tried with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone confirm if he managed to create blockchain wallet using Ajax call or they don't support CORS for this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Hamza

Answer (score 1):

I think it is safe to say that blockchain does not support CORS for their wallet API.

Your AJAX call above looks correct and you are getting a CORS blocked error.

And unlike some of their other APIs, the blockchain wallet API docs at https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api do **not** specify that calls are available via CORS with the cors=true query parameter.

There are some significant security implications when dealing with private keys and passwords in the browser using javascript.  I suspect that is why they do not allow it.